# How would I print a string obtained from a user in reverse?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm stuck on an exercise where I must obtain a string from a user and then print it in reverse with each letter on its own line. I've done this successfully with a for loop but I was wondering how to do so without it.

```
user_string = input("Please enter a string: ")  

for letter in (user_string)[::-1]:
    print(letter)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi ccharp! I see you are new to SO (stackoverflow). This question is against guidelines, please read them before posting a question.

Comment: @tdelaney i see it was edited. When this question was first posted it had no code example.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse and use `str.join` to rebuild the string.

```
print("\n".join(reversed(input("Please enter a string: "))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many characters there are in the string or array (calculate using the length method `len()`) then you could do:

```
while i < arr_length:
```

with i incrementing at the end of every round.

The rest of the code would be the same but using i as an index.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to cast the string to a list and use the `list.pop()` method until there are no characters left in the list.

```
user_input = list(input())
while len(user_input) > 0:
    print(user_input.pop())
```

[`list.pop()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) will remove the last item in the list and return it.

Answer (score 0):

def reverse(s):
str = ""
for i in s:
str = i + str
return str

s = "Geeksforgeeks"

print("The original string is : ", end="")
print(s)

print("The reversed string(using loops) is : ", end="")
print(reverse(s))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please fix the formatting in your post. You can refer to the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page for guidance. Also, please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Using index property we can easily reverse a given string

```
a = input()
print(a[::-1])
```